# Incorrect data when we using the CONVERT_TZ  function on DST boundaries

Tags: mysql

We have a problem in converting time zone from "America/New_York" to "UTC". This problem occurs only on times representing 2.00 AM during the daylight saving.

1. Timezone conversion with correct output

   ```
   mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ("2012-03-10 02:11:00", "America/New_York" , "UTC");
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   | CONVERT_TZ("2012-03-10 02:11:00", "America/New_York" , "UTC") |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   | 2012-03-10 07:11:00 |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.11 sec)
   ```
2. Timezone conversion with wrong output

   ```
   mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ("2012-03-11 02:11:00", "America/New_York" , "UTC");
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   | CONVERT_TZ("2012-03-11 02:11:00", "America/New_York" , "UTC") |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   | 2012-03-11 07:00:00 |
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

Comment: 02:11am "doesn't exist" on March 11th 2012 in America/New_York. I'm not sure what conversion you'd expect.